# how to hide menu icon based on tab change listener functionality?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am developing an android application,In that i need to hide/menu visible  menu item  based on tab click functionality.When ontap,

1.invitation_tab "settings icon" only visible in the menu board

2.when ontap event_tab "create_occasion icon " only visible in the menu board

3.similarly when ontap Groupchat_tab "dropdown icon" only visible in the menu board .

how to achieve this ,please help me.

My layout is looking below,

[image]

Menu coding is below,

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appmunu="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="ringee.app.com.ringeeapp.UserDashBoard">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/dropdown"
        android:icon="@drawable/dropdown_icon"
        android:title="Dropdown"
        appmunu:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/all"
                android:title="All" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/event"
                android:title="Event" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/invitation"
                android:title="Invitation" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/create_occasion"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_event"
        android:title="Create Occasion"
        appmunu:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/account_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/profile_image" />

</menu>
```

My Activity coding is below,

```
    public class UserDashBoardActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String TAB_1_TAG = "Invitation";
    private static final String TAB_2_TAG = "Event";
    private static final String TAB_3_TAG = "GroupChat";
    private FragmentTabHost tabHost;
    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityContext(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStoped();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onPause();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStoped();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user_dash_board, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_dash_board);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Get TabHost Refference
        tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_1_TAG).setIndicator("Invitation"), InvitationFragment.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_2_TAG).setIndicator("Event"), OccasionFragment.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_3_TAG).setIndicator("GroupChat"), GroupChatFragment.class, null);

        // Set drawable images to tab
        /*tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_event);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_phone);

        // Set Tab1 as Default tab and change image
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_action_person);*/
        //invitation tab highlighted by default
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Orange));
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.scandal));
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.scandal));

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {

                setTabColor(tabHost);
            }
        });


    }

    //setTabColor method added for highlighting the tabs
    public void setTabColor(FragmentTabHost tabHost) {

        for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.scandal));//unselected

        if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==0)    
       tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Orange)); //1st tab selected

        else if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==1)
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Orange)); //2nd tab selected
        else if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==2)
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Orange)); //3rd tab selected
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        // noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.account_settings) {
            Intent userSettingIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityUserSettings.class);
            userSettingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(userSettingIntent);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.profile) {
            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ImageUploadActivity.class);
            profileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(profileIntent);
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.create_occasion){

                Intent occasionAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OccasionActivity.class);
                // Clears History of Activity
                occasionAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(occasionAct);

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```